# jScrollPane scrollTo (horizontally) setting, strange flickering

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, jscrollpane

I am having a strange issue with jScrollPane plugin. After several days of using several settings, I still don't find my mistake. The problem is when using scrollTo function from jScrollPane it makes a strange thing. To see what I mean, go to this http://jsfiddle.net/DJb6U/, and click on the 'click me' grey div. Look at the left of the RESULT as the div is scrolling. The scroll goes 1 pixel left and then it goes right as it should. What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just something I want to point out ,when coding its always better practice to use meaningful variable names instead of variables like i or j etc. It makes debugging your code easier and your colleagues will appreciate the effort.:)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In fact it made me find the (stupid) solution. #main div had a 1px border that was creating that strange behaviour. Here is the Fiddle corrected.http://jsfiddle.net/FVnhU/ .Thanks again.

Comment: No, It seemed corrected, but not. Does anyone see the same problem?

Comment: Happens in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Please any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a bug of the component. See http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to_animate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of the component.

See http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to_animate.html. The page have the same problem you are having.

Do a breakpoint at line **#756** in http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js to start resolving the issue.

Mathematics are not helping here. The component is not doing quite well it calculation. It left precition.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty, although I spected a solution for the problem as well as confirming the bug. I finally ended up using http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 iscroll. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[enter link description here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)I had the same problem, too, but could resolve it by using the plugin defined properties at the end of the jScrollPane.js file.

Have a look at them, it's worth trying them.

The following code gave a quite reasonable solution:

```
showMe.find('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    autoReinitialiseDelay: 10
});
```

Comment: I deleted the option `autoReinitialise : true`, and only left `autoReinitialiseDelay: 10`. Both combined, it implied as a side-effect that the CPU was heavily loaded. I strongly suggest to read the jScrollPane documentation and have a look at the demos about reinitialise on Kevin Luck webpage [http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented jCarousel in a similar fashion for some projects. It does not have the same problem and it's quite easy to implement and customize.

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: Thanks but I am not trying to achieve an image carousel, but a horizontal layout site.